# pagingToolbar not working for transform grid

Tags: extjs, grid, transform

I am transforming HTML table into extjs grid using:

`var myGrid = Ext.create('Ext.ux.grid.TransformGrid', "the-table", {
...
...
}`

My pagingToolbar does not work.

It shows total number of records correct. When I click next/previous buttons, it shows correct page numbers but inside grid, page is not turned. Grid shows all records upfront.

Code I am using is:

```
var _pagingToolbar = new Ext.PagingToolbar({
displayInfo : true,
pageSize : 10,
dock: 'bottom',
displayMsg: 'Displaying topics {0} - {1} of {2}',
emptyMsg: "No topics to display"
});


var myGrid = Ext.create('Ext.ux.grid.TransformGrid', "the-table", {

...
...
...
bbar: _pagingToolbar
});

_pagingToolbar.bindStore(myGrid.getStore());
var store=myGrid.getStore();
store.pageSize=10;

myGrid.render();
```

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance...

PS: Posted on Sencha forum as well...

Regards,
Waheed

Comment: Actually I managed to solve it myself. Issue is in ExtJS in TransformGrid plugin file. I simple edited TransformGrid.js in ux folder and changed "type: 'memory'," ==> "type: 'pagingmemory',"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I managed to solve it myself.

Issue is in ExtJS in TransformGrid plugin file.

I simple edited TransformGrid.js in ux folder and on line 93, I changed

```
type: 'memory',
```

to

```
type: 'pagingmemory',
```